# Delivering NFC data to only my application not any other application

Tags: android, nfc

Hi I am developing simple application in which i am using NFC functionality of android. I Wrote one simple application which write simple text on NFC tag and other application which reads that text.

My problem is that I am writing simple text message. But if there are two readers are available then it gives me options for both. I don't want that any other application listen for NFC tag data. so how to do that. How to restrict other application to read my data.
Or in other way only my application should listen for that tag no other application.

Comment: I'm not very familar with NFC, but I read the basics so far I can tell you that you can create a NDEF where you can limit the data for just your app.

Comment: ok So I have to readers package name write ?

Comment: I cannot remeber that exactly look for NFC google io 2012 or 2011 videos there was that good explained.

Comment: Ok rekire thank you for help. I will check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDEF Message can contain more than one NDEF Record. You can add Android Application Record (AAR) to your message.

If a tag contains an AAR, the tag dispatch system dispatches in the following manner:

1. Try to start an Activity using an intent filter as normal. If the
   Activity that matches the intent also matches the AAR, start the
   Activity.
2. If the Activity that filters for the intent does not match
   the AAR, if multiple Activities can handle the intent, or if no
   Activity handles the intent, start the application specified by the
   AAR.
3. If no application can start with the AAR, go to Google Play to
   download the application based on the AAR.

More about AAR you can read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar

Comment: Thank you tsypa for replay. I did in same way as u say with AAR and its working fine. Thank you.